# Coroutines: Can't return value after finish work

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In my android app I need after executed some long network operation to return result (e.g. after 10 seconds)

here snippet:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                lateinit var response: Response<Void>
                response = executeOperations.await()
                return response
            }
```

but I get compile error in this line:

```
return response
```

Error message:

```
'return' is not allowed here
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work like that. Your `return` is not allowed there because you are inside a `coroutine context` on those `{ }`

But actually the best way to do it is to create some method and handle that response instead of returning it. On your case I'm a little confused:

Transform:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                lateinit var response: Response<Void>
                response = executeOperations.await()
                return response
            }
```

Into:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                lateinit var response: Response<Void>
                response = executeOperations.await()
                 withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                  handleResponse(response)
               }
            }
```

Plus, your heavy work musn't happen in the `Dispatchers.Main` but in `Dispatchers.IO`